# email regular expression in javascript based on mentioned points

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, email, input

Could any one please provide the regular expression for below conditions

1. User-part does not begin or end with a “.” Character.
2. Domain-part does not contain the following invalid characters: "#\"%|<>?'`/
   ,*&;:£$^!~ ú(){}+"
3. Valid email has ‘@’ and ‘.’ Character
4. Valid email does not contains two consecutive dots

Currently I am using the below reg ex

```
 /^(?!^[.])[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63})*$/;
```

The mentioned regular expression is not working all points.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would tell what points fail on your current expression. Your current conditions would accept `example@a[b=c]d.com` which is invalid per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Comment: If what you actually want is a regexp to accurately validate real-world addresses, prepare to be shocked as it is surprisingly difficult. There's one on http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html and it does not cope with "arbitratily nested comments". Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#cite_ref-21

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: TLD list: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db ; valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 1):

To respect all these conditions you need to treat them in order and take a logic where you write your regex in parts, I tried to make a suitable solution for your case and this is **[the Regex](https://regex101.com/r/a4NS2I/2/)** I came up with:

```
(?!^[.])[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+[a-zA-Z_\-0-9.]+(?!\.\.)[^\.]+@(?![#\"%|<>?'`\/ ,*&;:£$^!~ ú(){}+])(?![\.]{2})[a-zA-Z_\-0-9.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}
```

**Demo:**

You can [test this **Regex** here](https://regex101.com/r/a4NS2I/2/) and see it in [a working **live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/1fa0wyL2/1/) too.

### Explanation:

- Negative Lookahead `(?!^[.])`

> Assert that the Regex below does not match `^` asserts position at start
>   of the string Match a single character present in the list below `[.]` .
>   matches the character `.` literally (case sensitive)

- Match a single character present in the list below `[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+`

> I added this part to avoid matching the `.` in the beginning of the
>   regex
>   `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `a-z` a single character in
>   the range between `a` and `z` (case sensitive), `A-Z`
>   a single character in the range between `A` and `Z`
>   `_` matches the character _ literally (case sensitive) - matches the character - literally (case sensitive) `0-9` a single character in the
>   range between `0` and `9`

- Match a single character present in the list below `[a-zA-Z_\-0-9.]+`

> `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `a-z` a single character in
>   the range between `a` and `z` (case sensitive), `A-Z`
>   a single character in the range between `A` and `Z`
>   `_` matches the character _ literally (case sensitive) - matches the character - literally (case sensitive) `0-9` a single character in the
>   range between `0` and `9`,  `.` matches the character `.` literally (case sensitive)

- Negative Lookahead `(?!\.\.)`

> Assert that the Regex below does not match `\.` matches the character .
>   literally (case sensitive) `\.` matches the character `.` literally

- Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\.]+`

> `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many
>   times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `\.` matches the
>   character `.` literally

- `@` matches the character `@` literally
- Negative Lookahead `(?![#\"%|<>?'\/ ,*&;:£$^!~ ú(){}+])`

> Assert that the Regex below does not match Match a single character
>   present in the list below `[#\"%|<>?'`/ ,*&;:£$^!~ ú(){}+]`

- Negative Lookahead `(?![\.]{2})`

> Assert that the Regex below does not match Match a single character
>   present in the list below `[\.]{2}`, `{2}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 2
>   times `\.` matches the character `.` literally

- Match a single character present in the list below `[a-zA-Z_\-0-9.]+`

> `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many
>   times as possible, giving back as needed  `a-z` a single
>   character in the range between `a` and `z` (case
>   sensitive), `A-Z` a single character in the range between `A`
>   and `Z` (case sensitive)
>   `_` matches the character _ literally (case sensitive) - matches the character - literally (case sensitive) `0-9` a single character in the
>   range between `0` and `9`, `.` matches
>   the character `.` literally (case sensitive) `\.` matches the character `.`
>   literally

- Match a single character present in the list below `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}`

> `{2,3}` Quantifier — Matches between `2` and `3` times, as many times as
>   possible, giving back as needed `a-z` a single character in the
>   range between `a` and `z` (case sensitive), `A-Z` a
>   single character in the range between `A` and `Z`

Comment: Thanks. I tried to validate the validate the email with your solution but it was not showing error for ".test@test.com" and for remaining scenarios It was working fine. Please help for the scenario User-part does not begin with a "." character. I tried in http://jsfiddle.net/1fa0wyL2/

Comment: @lakshmi I updated [**the regex**](https://regex101.com/r/a4NS2I/3) and the [**demo** as well](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/1fa0wyL2/1/) to use this regex: `/(?!^[.])[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+[a-zA-Z_\-0-9.]+(?!\.\.)[^\.]+@(?![#\"%|<>?'\/ ,*&;:£$^!~ ú(){}+])(?![\.]{2})[a-zA-Z_\-0-9.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}/g`, and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var component = {
    input   : $('input[name="email"]'),
    mensage : {
        fields  : $('.msg'),
        success : $('.success'),
        error   : $('.error')
    }
},
    regex  = /^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?@[a-z][a-zA-Z-0-9]*\.[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?$/;

component.input.blur(function () {
    component.mensage.fields.hide();
    regex.test(component.input.val()) ? component.mensage.success.show() : component.mensage.error.show();
});
```

```css
.msg {
    display: none;
}
.error {
    color: red;
}
.success {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="email" id="email">Hey!</label>
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="required" /> 
<span class="msg error">You shall not pass!</span>
<span class="msg success">You can pass!</span>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the handy code snippet that makes testing easy. This answer does not conform to the exact rules asked in the question. OP rejects a list of invalid chars, you state which you accept. This doesn't match on `[=]_~` and your answer is closer to RFC rules. Still, this answer should *not* be used to validate address reflecting real-worlds scenario as it reject valid addresses. Example: `me@4chan.org` `me@37signals.com` `me+a-b@c.com.` `1234phonenumber@mailtophone.someprovider.net` and many more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples .

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon yes you are right bro !!! but you mean it wrong lakshmi wants to full-fill only this conditions.